# unity rotation issue on parent rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

at first, here the video of the problem:
[link to video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMtkUB4sXhA&feature=youtu.be), here the [package](http://www.file-upload.net/download-6745903/rotation.rar.html)
and here is a screenshot of the hierachey:
[image]
the GUN is the parent with the script(empty gameobject) Suspension gets dropped to the `towerRotateObj` and Gun gets dropped on the `turretRotateObj`. Suspension and Gun are also empty gameobjects. they are just some kind of group objects
and here the code:

```
public class WeaponMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public GameObject turretRotateObj;
    public GameObject towerRotateObj;

    public float maxTowerRotationSpeed = 360.0f;
    public float maxTurretRotationSpeed = 360.0f;

    public float smoothFactorTower = 0.125f;
    public float smoothFactorTurret = 0.125f;

    public float maxTowerRotation = 130.0f;
    public float maxTurretRotation = 50.0f;

    private Vector3 m_newRotation;
    private Vector3 m_angles;
    private float m_minTowerAngle;
    private float m_maxTowerAngle;
    private float m_minTurretAngle;
    private float m_maxTurretAngle;
    private float m_velTower;
    private float m_velTurret;

    private bool m_isTransNecTower = false;
    private bool m_isTransNecTurret = false;

    // initialization
    void Start()
    {
       m_newRotation = Vector3.zero;
       m_angles = Vector3.zero;

       m_maxTowerAngle = towerRotateObj.transform.eulerAngles.y + maxTowerRotation/2;
       m_minTowerAngle = towerRotateObj.transform.eulerAngles.y - maxTowerRotation/2;

       m_maxTurretAngle = turretRotateObj.transform.eulerAngles.z + maxTurretRotation/2;
       m_minTurretAngle = turretRotateObj.transform.eulerAngles.z - maxTurretRotation/2;

       // check if rotation happens between 0/360
       // tower
       if(m_minTowerAngle <= 0.0f)
         m_minTowerAngle += 360.0f;

       if(m_maxTowerAngle >= 360.0f)
         m_maxTowerAngle -= 360.0f;

       if(m_minTowerAngle > m_maxTowerAngle)
         m_isTransNecTower = true;

       // turret
       if(m_minTurretAngle <= 0.0f)
         m_minTurretAngle += 360.0f;

       if(m_maxTurretAngle >= 360.0f)
         m_maxTurretAngle -= 360.0f;

       if(m_minTurretAngle > m_maxTurretAngle)
         m_isTransNecTurret = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
       m_newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - towerRotateObj.transform.position).eulerAngles;
       m_angles = towerRotateObj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
       towerRotateObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_angles.x,
         ClampAngle(Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(m_angles.y, 
          m_newRotation.y - 90.0f, 
          ref m_velTower, 
          smoothFactorTower, 
          maxTowerRotationSpeed), m_minTowerAngle, m_maxTowerAngle, m_isTransNecTower),
         m_angles.z);

       m_newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - turretRotateObj.transform.position).eulerAngles;
       m_angles = turretRotateObj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
       turretRotateObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_angles.x,
         m_angles.y,
         ClampAngle(Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(m_angles.z, 
          -m_newRotation.x, 
          ref m_velTurret,
          smoothFactorTurret, 
          maxTurretRotationSpeed), m_minTurretAngle, maxTurretRotation, m_isTransNecTurret));
    }

    private float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max, bool isTranslationNecessary)
    {
       if(!isTranslationNecessary)
       {
         if(angle < min )
          return min;

         if(angle > max)
          return max;
       }
       else
       {
         if(angle > max && angle < min)
         {
          if(min - angle > angle - max)
              return max;
          else
              return min;
         }
       }

       return angle;
    }
}
```

so, it a similar setup, like the tower and gun of a tank....
i have posted that question already [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/335246/unity-rotation-issue-on-parent-rotation.html), but it seems like few people seen the post... any advice is appreciated! thanks.

update:

```
    m_newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(m_target.transform.position - towerRotateObj.transform.position).eulerAngles;
    m_newRotation.y -= 90f;
    m_angles = towerRotateObj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    towerRotateObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_angles.x, m_newRotation.y, m_angles.z);

    m_newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(m_target.transform.position - turretRotateObj.transform.position).eulerAngles;
    m_angles = turretRotateObj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    turretRotateObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_angles.x, m_angles.y, -m_newRotation.x);
```

the problem stays the same :(

Comment: The post is too big. Unlikely someone would spend all the time needed to understand what THE QUESTION is. Neither would look for an answer. Try to ask a detailed question with only the most relevant code provided.

Comment: very helpful. how to shorten, if i have no idea what the problem is. if you have a look on the video, you see the problem, if i would write what happens, it would take even longer to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my guess, gimbal lock, like said in the other answer. However, I'm not sure I would try to fix THAT, considering you are passing quaternion to euler and vise versa. If I had to do it, I wouldn't do it the way you did, since using quaternion for parenting between objects is equal to massive headache.

First, while you are parenting objects, you are not using that feature! This is a very solid feature from Unity. Unity Parenting: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html

Each of your turret objects only rotate in a single local axis. And Unity is built to handle that: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html

When an object is parented to another, you can rotate it locally in the axis you want. Unity handle the overall matrix transformation on its own. When you are modifying the global rotation of the object, you are basically overriding the transformation coming from the parenting. At this point, it's very easy for any hierarchy to gain error and imprecision over time.

EDIT: With your package, I was able to write what I meant:

```
public class WeaponMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boat;
    public GameObject turretRotateObj;
    public GameObject towerRotateObj;
    public GameObject target;

    private Vector3 lastDirection;

    // initialization
    void Start()
    {
        lastDirection = boat.transform.forward;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Find direction toward our target. Use turret as origin.
        Vector3 wantedDirection = target.transform.position - turretRotateObj.transform.position;
        // Rotate our last direction toward that new best direction. Change floats to make it move faster or slower.
        lastDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(lastDirection, wantedDirection, 0.01f, 0.01f);

        // Find the direction local to the tower as the boat can move around!
        Vector3 towerDirection = boat.transform.InverseTransformDirection(lastDirection);
        // Remove unwanted axis
        towerDirection = new Vector3(-towerDirection.z, 0, towerDirection.x);
        towerDirection.Normalize();
        // Set local rotation
        towerRotateObj.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(towerDirection);

        // Find the direction local to the gun, as the tower may have rotated!
        Vector3 turretDirection = towerRotateObj.transform.InverseTransformDirection(lastDirection);
        // Remove unwanted axis.
        turretDirection = new Vector3(turretDirection.x, turretDirection.y, 0);
        turretDirection.Normalize();
        // Set local rotation
        turretRotateObj.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(turretDirection);
    }
}
```

Note: I had to move the gun's barrel to the Z axis instead of the X axis because I was lazy. So if you only copy paste this code, the barrel will be pointing toward the frame, but the gun will follow the target correctly.

Since the rotation are now local, you can spin the ship for years, and the gun will never get any offset.

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-6745903/rotation.rar.html this is the package. what do you mean with: you are not parenting your object between each other? as you might see on the picture of the post, i am using parenting...

Comment: @immerhart: Then why are you modifying the object global rotation instead of using "localRotation" and only rotating the object in one axis?

Comment: @immerhart: Here you go, with your package I was able to write what I meant. I updated my answer with the fix code.

Comment: it seems to work. can you tell me, what i made wrong? or why this behavior appeared? i just rotated the object, not local but it worked ok. i just don´t get why this behavior appeared.

Comment: @immerhart: A few things... First, you shouldn't take the last orientation and try to modify it, it's bound to stack imprecision over time. By having a fixed vector that isn't bound to any transformation space, you keep it valid and have a stable reference to use. Two, you shouldn't modify the global rotation when having parented object unless you are absolutely sure it is what you want to do. I'm yet to encounter that case. Three, jumping between euler and quaternion is rarely a good idea. Quaternion are gimbal lock proof, but not euler. I prefer to stick with vector and matrix transform.

Comment: @immerhart: Now... Which part exactly was gaining an imprecision? I don't know. And by experience, I've learned not to try to track those, as it's long, painful and doesn't give much information, but to make code that make it impossible to stack imprecision. The best way to do this, is to refresh your variable each frame with data that you know is valid and carry, if possible, nothing or as little as possible from one frame to the next. And if you do, to use values that you know cannot affect the final result of your code.

Comment: the point is, i try to avoid to create objects in the Update(), because it cost decent amount of time (obejct creation)... not sure if this was the problem. but it works now. so something was wrong :)

Comment: @immerhart: Object... You mean like a Vector3? Well, I wouldn't care that much unless you plan to deploy on an old gameboy or have a hundred turrets on screen. Variables create and destroyed on the stack are normally very fast. But if you really care that much about declaration time, you can create a few field and bypass the new declaration I've put in. But normally, don't do it unless you have proof that it is a real bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure but it seems like you are running into [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) problem. Although your calculations start from quaternions it might be possible that the two calls to `Mathf.SmoothDampAngle` are the root cause on the long run.

So I would suggest to first remove all smoothing and then, if this turned out to be the culprit, replace these methods by pure quaternion based method like [Quaternion.Slerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html).

Comment: another point is, that i am rotating just one axis at a time and not all three at the same time. so, can gimbal lock happen? furthermore i am using only quaternions as you said(in the update).. :|
no, idea. i am bad in math

Answer (score 0):

After changing from Update to [LateUpdate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe I'm not thrashing the rotation like you were, but I think the gizmo's rotations were being applied before and after the turret's rotation and error was accumulating.

Comment: If so, an error will also accumulate while the game is running, and the error will become visible with any aging test. The code should be built in view that an offset or an error could never accumulate over time.

Comment: That's what switching to LateUpdate does.

Comment: It would do it on LateUpdate anyway as he is modifying a previous global rotation. There's bound to have imprecision when done that way, as you stack the float imprecision at each frames and you never get rid of it.